# Displaying a list of followers and people following

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, rubygems

Hell All,

I am using a ruby gem called socialization (https://github.com/cmer/socialization)

I have it working and I am able to follow and unfollow a user and see how many people are following or followed by any user. the issue is when I want to output the usernames of the followers and following, it only works for user1, and for user 2-4 it will show the usernames in order based on how many followers e.g. if the table is

- user1 follows => user 2
- user2 follows => user 3

and I ask for the followers for user 3 (knowing user3 as 1 follower) it will print out User1 regardless (i hope this makes sense)

Here is my code:

Followers method in UsersController

```
def followers
     @user = User.find(params[:user])
     @followers = @user.followers(User)
     @users = User.all

     response = {:user => @user, :followers => @followers, :users => @users}

     respond_to do |format|
      format.html  #followers.html.erb
      format.xml {render :xml => response}
    end
end
```

Following method in UsersController

```
def following
     @user = User.find(params[:user])
     @following = @user.followers(User)
     @users = User.all

     response = {:user => @user, :following => @following, :users => @users}

     respond_to do |format|
      format.html  #following.html.erb
      format.xml {render :xml => response}
    end
end
```

following View:

```
<p><u>Following</u></p>

<% (1..(@following.count)).each do |i| %>

    <% if @users[i].followed_by?(@user) %> 
  <p> <%= @users[i].username %> </p>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Followers view

```
<p><u>Followers</u></p>

<% (1..(@followers.count)).each do |i| %>

    <% if @users[i].follows?(@user) %> 
  <p> <%= @users[i].username %> </p>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My route

```
  resources :users do
  match 'show/:id' => 'user#show'
  collection do
    get 'follow'
    get 'unfollow'
    get 'followers'
    get 'following'
  end
```

the only one that seems to work correctly is `/users/followers?user=1`

everything else either shows nothing or the wrong names.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting all the followers in `@followers`, so use that in your view:

```
<p><u>Followers</u></p>

<% @followers.each do |f| %> # f object is of type User.
  # You don't need the if statement that you had,
  # because you already know that they are followers.
  <p> <%= f.username %> </p>
<% end %>
```

This will print the username of each `follower`. The other issues you have are that your followers and following methods do the same thing, check the docs for your gem to figure out how to get `following` and then structure your view for that similarly.

Comment: Thanks! it worked! .. I realized I had followers and not followees in my following method, and doing the loop the way you said instead of the way I did worked perfect!

Comment: You're welcome, good luck. The [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) are a fantastic resource for beginners.